# How to reduce large image size in Android?

Tags: android, xml, mobile, radio-button, imageview

I've a two forms like this :

[image: http://i58.servimg.com/u/f58/15/03/56/35/111.png]

With the next code :

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroupTypeAction"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_service"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:button="@drawable/button_service_selector" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_reception"
                android:button="@drawable/button_defense_selector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_passe"
                android:button="@drawable/button_passe_selector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_attaque"
                android:button="@drawable/button_attaque_selector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/button_bloc"
                android:button="@drawable/button_bloc_selector"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />
     </RadioGroup>
```

My RadioButton are too large for their RadioGroup, they are cut to the right...

How can I do so that my RadioButton take the size in width of the RadioGroup (=250dp) ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: `android:layout_marginLeft="725dp"` ... really? such a big margin??

Comment: You're right. ^^ But it's not my problem, I deleted it.

Comment: layout_width="match_parent" for each, because I want 250dp in width for each radiobutton.

Comment: Anyway, maybe the font you used is too big and/or the drawables contain too much space in the sides.

Comment: "layout_height" is useless for each button, i removed them and the result is the same (code update in message)
Each button is an image.
Thank you anyway.

Comment: But the images are too big

Comment: Exactly, that's my question!
There is not a method to reduce an image?

Comment: ... Photoshop? GIMP? The best would be that you have the images at each proper dpi (at least the images at 480 dpi for the xxhdpi resolution) for each drawable folder.

Comment: Yes but...250 dp = ? pixels ...

Comment: Depends... on an mdpi phone screen (160 dpi) - typically 320*480 px, I'd set the width to somewhat like 120px. so, for an xxhdpi screen (3 * mdpi), I'd say 360 px @ 480 dpi. This will scale down to 120 px @ 160 dpi. And you set it as 120 dp.

Answer (score 0):

change the widths to

```
android:layout_width="250dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Problem 1 - Graphics

By specifying `android:button` you are taking away the default `(o)` graphics. Since you only change background color try changing `android:background` instead.

### Problem 2 - Size

If you want the size of `RadioGroup` to be `250dp` change it like this

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="250dp" >
```

and if you want your `RadioButton`s to be exactly as wide

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Also if you would like all the `RadioButton`s to have same height, add this

```
<RadioButton
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

They will now divide all space inside `RadioGroup`. (Instead of `0dp` you could use anything but it would get overwritten anyway. `0dp` is most efficient.)